# build a new nested object with bracket notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a new nested object based on bracked notation. my syntax is

```
metaObj[subCat][attribute] = value;
```

and I have these variables;
My goal is to achieve this structure

```
metaObj = {
   chart : {
      x: "random",
      y: 123
   },
   data : {
      x: "random",
      y: 123
   }
}
```

I should build it dynamically since the attribute names and categories might change in every scenario

I receive this error though

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ---- of undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says that it cannot set property of undefined because the `subCat` is undefined.

A solution would be to first define it as an object and then do your thing.

```
metaObj = {}; 
metaObj[subCat] = {}; // define the subCat ( metaObj: {subCat: {}})
metaObj[subCat][attribute] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's becoz you are trying to set the value for an object that is not yet created.
Assuming that the metaObj is already initialized with {}

```
if(!metaObj[subCat]) {
 metaObj[subCat]= {};
 metaObj[subCat][attribute] = value;
} else {
 metaObj[subCat][attribute] = value;
}
```